# Correctly grant access to packaged Named Credentials

Tags: managed-package, permission-sets, isv, namedcredentials

My Managed Package uses External APIs and packages `External Credential` and `Named Credential` artifacts.

[image]

I also have packaged a Permission Set, and I tried hard to make use those packaged Credentials. But it seems like this is not possible.

The users still get this error when my managed code uses the `Named Credential`.

> The callout couldn't access the endpoint. You might not have the
> required permissions, or the named credential "namespace__OpenAi"
> might not exist.

Even if I create a new Permission Set after installation and assign it, it fails with the same error.

[image]

Comment: How come the final screenshot doesn't show a value for "Installed Package" column against the "OpenAI - OpenAIAPI" entry?

Comment: I don't know. Its definitely coming from the Managed Package. It's also strange that I can delete the packaged Named Credentials.

Comment: @PhilW do you know how to already link Permsets to new-generation External Credentials. I can link them but the link is NOT in the Metadata of the Permset.

Comment: Sorry Robert, I haven't had to deal with that (yet).

Comment: We went back to Legacy Named Creds because of the lack of Perm Set support. It seems like they're another half-baked invention by Salesforce. Also, there were two threads on this topic in PCommunity fairly recently (the first here: https://partners.salesforce.com/0D54V00006tN4FJ and it links to the other one in my comment) which basically say that Named Creds aren't Managed Package friendly.

Comment: @daveespo I see. This is what my gut feeling said. But how would I be able to package a Legacy NC for an API linked to a packaged permset and allow subscribers to add parameters like ApiKeys and Secrets. Is that even possible with Legacy? Or do I need to resort to Custom Settings then?

Comment: Based on that thread that the Salesforce PM had on the PCommunity post related to the one I referenced, he advocated for exactly that -- if you need to package a secret, a Protected CMDT is the way to go. If you need to have a per-subscriber secret, you can either use a Custom Setting or have the subscriber create the Named Cred and provide a Setting for your app to know which Named Cred to use (we've never actually used a Named Cred in packaged code for this reason -- too hard)

Comment: @daveespo could you please create an Answer because this is super helpful and needed as nobody know that. Would be great if you could cite and link the original sources.

Comment: A lot of the auth-related metadata components are rife with nuances when it comes to managed packages. For example, some documentation states Auth Providers cannot be included in managed packages but this is only half-true. If you include a legacy NC or external credential that references an Auth Provider then it *will* be installed to subscriber orgs, though it won't be namespace-protected and the consumer secret will automatically rotate for each subscriber. It seems a similar thing occurs with ECs and that's why there was no value under the "Installed Package" column in your screenshot.

Comment: On the [Spring'24 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_named_credentials_managed_packages.htm&release=248&type=5), it is said that now you can "Distribute Named Credentials with Second-Generation Managed and Unlocked Packages". 

However, I'm having the same issue: without the "User External Credentials" read Object Setting in the PS you cannot see the EC (even if you have access to its Principal through the PS), and when deploying your PS inside a Managed Package, this permission gets removed. What has changed then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "new" External Credentials are not supported for 2GP packaging per the Metadata Coverage report:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/58

Legacy Named Credentials are generally inappropriate for Managed Package usage because they can be used by any code in the subscriber org. Said differently: If you're shipping a secret in your managed package, you should use a Protected Custom Metadata Type record. (This recommendation was provided by Salesforce Security Review Office Hours)

For secrets that vary from subscriber to subscriber and need to be provisioned into each org, that's where a Protected Custom Setting (and UI to allow the subscriber to set it) or providing them with laborious instructions for creating a Named Credential (new or legacy) may be appropriate.

A separate, but related, thread was created which suggests against using Named Credentials in managed packages due to their brittleness when it comes to being updatable in a subscriber org. The PM for Named Credentials (Ross Belmont) said:

> The first blocker teams tend to face is the inability to include secret values in metadata; that will never be workable from a security
> standpoint since metadata can be accessed in plain text XML. Something
> would need to be done post-deploy to fill in the missing piece of
> configuration.
>
> Separately, we see that a surprisingly large percentage of the time,
> the full details about a remote endpoint can’t be known at packaging
> time. Sometimes, there’s a dynamic or custom subdomain, similar to how
> we have My Domain in our platform. A variation of this same idea is
> that the endpoint used in sandbox for testing is very often not the
> same endpoint in production. (Remote systems can have their own
> concept of sandbox or test environments.) These factors make adoption
> of Named Credentials among our AppExchange ISVs in particular lower
> than we’d like it to be.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000JgiQmSAJ

Lastly, IIRC, you can't grant access to the "new" External Credentials via Permission Set -- it can only be granted by Profile which seems to be absolutely backward with regard to Salesforce's recommendation to stop using Profiles to provide access.

Comment: What IMO is completely absurd is that you [can grant access to the EC Principal inside a PS](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_enable_ext_cred_principal.htm&type=5) but you still cannot see that EC. While working on your dev org you can use the [User External Credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_user_external_credentials.htm&type=5) Object Permission, but when you package it, no matter what permissions you have granted, they get removed. At least, it should retain the ability to see the ECs inside the package... or warn about it somewhere.