# Store settings and API credentials in packaged CMDT records

Tags: managed-package, customsetting, custom-metadata, isv, namedcredentials

My current Managed Package supports a single GPT API and covers that with multiple packaged components:

- `Protected Custom Setting` for secure storage of API credentials ([Named Creds don't work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/407261/256))
- `Custom Metadata Type record` for API- and app-specific settings

Now I want to allow multiple API providers to be switched or used together and I am thinking about just packaging multiple CMDT records of a single Provider__cmdt that combines everything: Custom Settings, Prepackaged defaults and Fields for API credentials.

---

**But I now wonder and ask for your insights:**

1. If CMDT are safe to store API credentials (especially for Security Review)
2. If CMDT records can be easily be updated using custom UI and Apex or if I need MetadataAPI and Connected App for that. ([see this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/389121/256))
3. If CMDT are in general a better type of Custom Setting and we should slowly migrate there.
4. Is using a Custom Object with proper Permission Sets recommended instead? Not packageable but UI and DML is easy?

Comment: Not a full answer: 1. Yes, this has been discussed on partner forums positively. 2. Yes, just so long as you carefully select developer management for the fields, not subscriber. 3. Yes, 100%. 4. No because it is too easy to accidentally leak permissions outside the package to anyone and you could compromise the external system. I'd go with a single MDT and packaged, protected records. You can then provide a write-only UI for updating. If the client is to create their own, they can have unprotected records (though note point 4). You could let them create package protected in your UI.

Comment: @PhilW Would love to have that as an answer for better visibility. No need to add more.

Comment: I added an extended version of the comment as an "answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My tuppence:

1. If CMDT are safe to store API credentials (especially for Security Review)

Yes, this has been discussed on partner forums positively.

2. If CMDT records can be easily be updated using custom UI and Apex or if I need MetadataAPI and Connected App for that.

Yes, just so long as you carefully select developer management for the fields, not subscriber.

This is done by doing a "deployment" using the built-in Apex Metadata API, so using Apex behind an LWC or flow using an invocable method.

3. If CMDT are in general a better type of Custom Setting and we should slowly migrate there.

Most definitely. The can be packaged and (if developer managed fields are to be updated) can be modified trivially in an upgrade (no code; just package the updated metadata).

Note, however, that if you're having the packaged records updated in the org you won't want to directly include the CMDT records, or you need to make sure the fields are subscriber managed to avoid them being overwritten.

You can, as I suspect you can understand from this mixed message around how fields should be managed, get into a bind if you're not careful. (We have protected CMDT records with subscriber manageable fields; upgrades to these fields do not happen even though the subscriber cannot access these protected records outside our codebase, and you cannot have the installer do the upgrade either via the Metadata API - a permissions error happens. We had to add a global Apex method the admin must run via anon apex after upgrade, which sucks.)

If you want the records to be updated by subscribers and avoid these being overwritten, you'll need to have your installer optionally do the creation rather than just include the metadata records in the package. This is, unfortunately, much what you have to do with custom settings...

I believe, since your installer is part of your namespace, you can have it create protected records that are invisible on the org.

CMDTs give you more flexibility going forward, and support long text fields (and some other types of field, including references between CMDT records) not supported in Custom Settings.

4. Is using a Custom Object with proper Permission Sets recommended instead? Not packageable but UI and DML is easy?

IMHO, no because it is too easy to accidentally leak permissions outside the package to anyone and you could compromise the external system. (I never managed to get custom object "protection" to work, but didn't try very hard.)

I'd go with a single MDT and packaged, protected records. You can then provide a write-only UI for updating. If the client is to create their own, they can have unprotected records (though note point 4). You could let them create package protected in your UI.

**UPDATE**:

We manipulate CMDT records using the built-in [Metadata.Operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Metadata_Operations.htm) API. This doesn't require any Connected Apps and doesn't require use of the Session ID. It's natively supported in Apex and can be used in your LWC back-end code or your post-install script as required.

Comment: I thought for DMLing CMDT record I run into this trap https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/389121/256. Can you please point me to code samples on how Apex can updated them without the complexities of Connected Apps and such?

Comment: WARNING: I implemented @PhilW's solution but found myself in a situation where my subscriber cannot update the CMDT. See https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000smLF8AAM/~

Comment: Looks like that is in the process of being fixed with a patch release?

Comment: I honestly don't understand it. Even a SysAdmin can use packaged Apex UI to update packaged records. I am only upgraditing Subscriber Editable fields and skipp Devonly Upgradable fields. Totally lost!

Comment: PhilW: here is my issue as a new question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/408084/256

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is simply to use a protected custom setting and build a UI with a password field input type for accepting passwords.

The Alternative approach is obviously to use Custom Metadata which, too needs to be protected. This approach involves a bit more work since creating and deploying custom metadata via [Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api) is a little more intense, and you might need  Platform events to communicate with your UI.

Answers to your queries

1. If CMDT are safe to store API credentials (especially for Security Review)

> Yes provided you make sure its only editable by the Apex in your namespace. There is a setting for that when you create these CMDT.

2. If CMDT records can be easily be updated using custom UI and Apex or if I need MetadataAPI and Connected App for that. (see this question)

> You can use Apex but note this is an asynchronous process and you would need to use platform events or polling to communicate status of deployment back to LWC. Not easy but extra code

3. If CMDT are in general a better type of Custom Setting and we should slowly migrate there.

> I don't think CMDT has a lot of advantages for this use case.

4. Is using a Custom Object with proper Permission Sets recommended instead? Not packageable but UI and DML is easy?

> Yes it is fine to use Custom Objects not necessarily recommended. You can also make the object hidden and not accessible via UI. I think there is a [setting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_hide_custom_objects_permissions.htm) for that too.

Comment: A few follow up questions which you might wanna add to your answer:

2. Can you provide Example code or links that show how to update CMDT record from Apex without calling Metadata API?
3. CMDT record with default values are packagable and you can package multiple records. Both cannot be done with Settings
4. Do you have an document describing how to use that. I never understood that part of FMA.

Comment: You have to call the Metadata API to update CMDT records, but at least you can use the built-in version.

Comment: @RobertSösemann You can have post install script to initially have custom settings populated!

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api This is trailhead for updating the metadata