# Packaged CMDT record fails to update even for Sysadmin

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, isv, platform-bug, metadata.operations

*Note: There is a related Salesforce Support Case #45059901*

---

Convinced by the [answers of some real ISV experts](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/407826/256), I refactored my Managed Release Package from ugly **Custom Settings to Custom Metadata** with packaged records.

As proposed by many, I made the overall CMDT `Public` and the single record that comes with the package `Protected`. This way my app is open for customer records but I own my records and keep them behind a packaged setup UI.

Furthermore, I chose **Field Manageability** settings for the fields to be SubscriberEditable.

[image]

Updating such a record from a packaged setup UI in the subscriber org, fails with:

> **Not allowed to install or modify metadata via Apex**

[image]

I am strongly convinced **it is not a permission issue**. Although the `Customize Application` and other [permissions from the packaged Permset are lost mostly due to this Known Issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000smLF8AAM/%7E), the user still has a Full System Admin Profile which grants basically all rights.

I also make sure the `DeveloperEditable` field `isIgnored` during `Metadata.Operations`:

```
public static void persist(MyCMDT__mdt record) {
    String prefix = record.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName().replace('__mdt', '');

    Metadata.CustomMetadata cmd = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
    cmd.fullName = prefix + '.' + record.QualifiedApiName;
    cmd.label = record.MasterLabel;

    for (String fieldName : record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet()) {
        if (isIgnored(fieldName)) {
            continue;
        }

        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
        customField.field = fieldName;
        customField.value = record.get(fieldName);

        cmd.values.add(customField);
    }

    Metadata.DeployContainer container = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
    container.addMetadata(cmd);

    Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(container, new DeployCallback());
}
```

Comment: I will have a look see if I can spot a difference between our working set up and what you have. In the meantime, is your custom UI being invoked from a typical session for a normal admin user at some point after installation, or is it initiated from the package's post install page?

Comment: No post install scripts. Normal UI invoked by a User with App Admin permset. Is a SysAdmin now. My hope was that it can be a Standard user one day with the right permset. But anyhow it doesn't even work from a Sysadmin.

Comment: Note: There is a related Salesforce Support Case #45059901

Comment: Looking at where we do this, the only difference I can see is that our custom metadata types are themselves "public" visibility, and we simply have "protected" records. We allow direct subscriber creation and management of extra records that are outside our namespace.

Comment: Oh maybe I got that wrong. You mean by making the type public but the packaged record private subscribers can via Standard Setup create own records (that our app can use or ignore) and we still can provide a UI on top of the packaged protected ones?

Comment: @PhilW what I find strange that my CMDT record is public. Can that be the root cause? How can I mitigate that. Since all of that is packaged released I can't change anything :-(

Comment: Your first comment back is what I was getting at - that's the sort of thing we've done. On the latter comment, is the package in use by customers already? Could you have support turn it back into a beta release?

Comment: (I'm feeling really bad that you have taken my advice and it's causing a problem for you. We did hit various bumps, which I believe I flagged in the original Q&A, but not the issue you seem to have...)

Comment: @PhilW I rolled the app with a brand new public CMDT with protected records and all field SubscriberEditable and the problem remains :-(

Comment: So, from our learning on this (with public CMDT and protected records) and as stated in my answer to your other question: "We have protected CMDT records with subscriber manageable fields; upgrades to these fields do not happen even though the subscriber cannot access these protected records outside our codebase, and you cannot have the installer do the upgrade either via the Metadata API - a permissions error happens. We had to add a global Apex method the admin must run via anon apex after upgrade, which sucks". The "ghost user" did not have permission to edit subscriber manageable fields...

Comment: ... but an admin on the org does have the ability to run apex in our package that can then successfully update the subscriber manageable fields on packaged, protected CMDT records.

Comment: I am not getting your last 2 comments. What should I do or better not fdo?

Comment: I'm saying that if your packaged apex is run, to update subscriber managed data, by an admin on the org, I would expect this to work without trouble. This is what we do. After install the admin runs a global method on a global class and this does all the required processing. For you, the method would be AuraEnabled instead of global, and would be called from your UI. It *should* just work, like it has for us. I haven't spotted where you are doing something radically different to us and don't understand why you get the error. Sorry :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heaven (or Google) finally send me [this article](https://www.avenga.com/magazine/deploying-custom-metadata-records-apex-code) about Apex Metadata Deployments which states that:

> When you develop a managed package, **only certified packages are
> allowed to use this feature** of deploying custom metadata records
> from Apex code.
>
> There is **“Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Versions via
> Apex” checkbox setting, which enables beta packages** to perform a
> custom metadata records deployment from Apex code. This checkbox can
> be found in Setup \ Build \ Develop \ Apex Settings menu in the setup
> configuration.

[image]

When I checked this box in any org where I installed the Managed Released Package Version everything worked as expected.

Because my Managed Package is **not a Security Review approved** one. Currently just an internal one.

The [official Salesforce document describing the reason](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_security.htm) behind this is here.

> Additionally, for managed packages, if the managed package is not
> approved by Salesforce via security review, Apex classes in the
> package cannot access metadata (public or protected) unless the Deploy
> Metadata from Non-Certified Package Versions via Apex org preference
> is enabled.

Comment: Was about to answer this for you but glad you got through it!

Comment: @MohithShrivastava This would have saved me from 3 deprecated CMDT types an 10 Package Versions. ;-)  Can you point me to a bit more detailed and official material please? Does that mean I need all internal orgs that use this tool to set this flag or go through a free Security Review?

Comment: Shared the docs and other links in an another answer

Answer (score 1):

The official docs that describe why you need the setting is shared [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_metadata_security.htm)

From the docs

> Be aware of security considerations when accessing metadata using Apex.
> Generally, Apex classes installed in the subscriber org can access any public, supported metadata type or component in the subscriber org. Protected metadata, such as a custom metadata type that’s been marked protected, can only be accessed by Apex classes in the same namespace as the protected metadata.

> Additionally, for managed packages, if the managed package is not approved by Salesforce via security review, Apex classes in the package cannot access metadata (public or protected) unless the Deploy Metadata from Non-Certified Package Versions via Apex org preference is enabled. This preference, located under **Setup | Apex Settings**, must be enabled if admins or developers are installing managed packages that haven’t passed security review for app testing or pilot purposes.

> For deployments, because `Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment()` uses asynchronous Apex, queued deployment jobs and deployment callbacks are counted as asynchronous jobs in the current org. Queued deployment jobs and callbacks are subject to org limits on asynchronous Apex.

> Apps that access metadata via Apex must notify users that the app can retrieve or deploy metadata in the subscriber org. For installs that access metadata, notify users in the description of your package. You can write your own notice, or use this sample:

> This package can access and change metadata outside its namespace in the Salesforce org where it’s installed.

Salesforce verifies the notice during the security review.